# How to validate email domain names in regexpression

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc

I changed the expression to

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+\.(com|org|net|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET|MIL|EDU)$‌​", ErrorMessage = "E-mail is not valid")]
```

But when I typed in .comz, the validation appears, but when I correct it with .com, the validation error will not go away. why?

I got the following email regexpression

```
[RegularExpression(@"[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}", ErrorMessage = "E-mail is not valid")]
```

I would it also to validate real domain names like org, com, biz etc... I found this snippet but I am not sure about to modify my existing expression. Thanks.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.(com|org|net|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET|MIL|EDU)$
```

Comment: try `@"^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+\.(com|org|net|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET|MIL|EDU)$"`

Comment: [Hot to Verify that Strings are in Valid Email Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf(v=vs.110).aspx) google works wonders if used properly ..

Comment: Don't use a regular expression.

Comment: write a test console app that uses this `CMD` `nslookup -type=mx <domain.name>` replace domain.name with `gmail.com` for instance and see the output in the command window

Comment: So you won't let anyone register with an email address ending in a country code, or any of the new TLDs?

Comment: That's a terrible regex, its may have been valid at some point in the early 2000s but no longer is, there are over 1,000  TLDs now - too many to validate individually.